# PHP/CSS change background image depending on running session

Tags: php, css, stylesheet

I have a problem changing the background image depending of what area I'm in.
If I open the file in the browser it looks like this: background-image: url('CHRISTIAN/images/forest.jpg');

```
<?php
session_start();

header("Content-type: text/css");

if($_SESSION['in_area']==false){
$backgroundimage = "url('CHRISTIAN/images/background.jpg')";
} else if($_SESSION['in_area']=="forest"){
$backgroundimage = "url('CHRISTIAN/images/forest.jpg')";
  } else if($_SESSION['in_area']=="graveyard"){
      $backgroundimage = "url('CHRISTIAN/images/graveyard.jpg')";
   }
?>

body {
    background-image: <?= $backgroundimage ?>;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: 2000px 1200px;
}
```

some working code in the same stylesheet:

```
$playerhealth = $_SESSION['hero_health_percentage']; 
$white = '#fff';
$dkgray = '#333';
$dkgreen = '#008400';
?>


#playerhpbar {
float: left;
width: 200px;
height: 20px;
border: 1px solid black;
background:<?= $dkgray ?>;
color:<?= $white ?>;
}

#playerhpbarcurrent {
float:left;
width: <?= $playerhealth ?>%;
height: 100%;
background-color:<?= $dkgreen ?>;
}
```

Comment: @ItayGal `<?=` == `<? echo`

Comment: Are you certain that `$_SESSION['in_area']` is set properly? Might want to `var_dump($_SESSION)`

Comment: I have even tried to do $_SESSION['in_area']="forest"; before executing the rest of the code, still no background changes.